# Error when saving composites id inside a for loop

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to persist some objects that have a composite id. If I am only sending an array with one element it works fine, but it the array has more than one it throws an exception when saving the first one.    public boolean

```
addParamsToChart(List<ChartParams> chartParams, Long chartId) {
        List<ChartParams> chartParamsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ChartParams chartParam: chartParams) {
            ChartParamsId id = new ChartParamsId();
            // id.setChartId(chartId);
            id.setChartId(chartParam.getChart().getId());
            id.setParamId(chartParam.getParam().getId());
            id.setContextSourceId(chartParam.getContextSource().getId());
            chartParam.setChartParamsId(id);
            if(chartParamsRepository.save(chartParams) !=null) {
                chartParamsList.add(chartParam);
            }
        }
        if(chartParamsList.size()!=chartParams.size()) {
            // something went wrong, delete previous inserted
            deleteChartParams(chartParamsList);
            chartRepository.delete(chartId);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

> [{
>       "chart": {
>           "id": 49,
>           "cv": {
>               "id": 1,
>               "name": "Money",
>               "category": {
>                   "id": 1,
>                   "name": "Euros"
>               },
>               "definition": "\"European curreny.\" [EU:euro]",
>               "enabled": true,
>               "cvid": "CC:1010"
>           },
>           "accountType": {
>               "id": 1,
>               "name": "saving"
>           },
>           "name": "Euro saving charts"
>       },
>       "param": {
>           "id": 8,
>           "name": "Totals",
>           "isFor": "Currency"
>       },
>       "contextSource": {
>           "id": 3,
>           "name": "euro",
>           "internal": "eu",
>           "abbreviatedName": "eu"
>       } }]

But for this having two objects inside instead of one is not working, throwing an exception at the first save.

> [{
>       "chart": {
>           "id": 52,
>           "cv": {
>               "id": 55,
>               "name": "Stocks",
>               "category": {
>                   "id": 1,
>                   "name": "Stocks"
>               },
>               "definition": "\"General stocks.\" [GS:ST]",
>               "enabled": true,
>               "cvid": "ST:0111"
>           },
>           "accountType": {
>               "id": 1,
>               "name": "saving"
>           },
>           "name": "Stock saving chart"
>       },
>       "param": {
>           "id": 8,
>           "name": "Totals",
>           "isFor": "Currency"
>       },
>       "contextSource": {
>           "id": 6,
>           "name": "stock",
>           "internal": "st",
>           "abbreviatedName": "st"
>       } }, {
>       "chart": {
>           "id": 52,
>           "cv": {
>               "id": 55,
>               "name": "Stocks",
>               "category": {
>                   "id": 1,
>                   "name": "Stocks"
>               },
>               "definition": "\"General stocks.\" [GS:ST]",
>               "enabled": true,
>               "cvid": "ST:0111"
>           },
>           "accountType": {
>               "id": 1,
>               "name": "saving"
>           },
>           "name": "Stock saving chart"
>       },
>       "param": {
>           "id": 8,
>           "name": "Totals",
>           "isFor": "Currency"
>       },
>       "contextSource": {
>           "id": 7,
>           "name": "Sold stock",
>           "internal": "st_sold",
>           "abbreviatedSequence": "st_sold"
>       } }]

The exception I got is:
**org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class eu.stocks.chart.chartParams.ChartParams**

Comment: Not answering your question, but instead of `something went wrong, delete previous inserted`, simply use `Transaction`.

Comment: I do not know what you mean with that. But thanks, I will look for it.